# Not able to pass a value to a then-fetch function

Tags: node.js, fetch

I am trying to pass a value "x" Inside fetch to the then function but in vain

```
    var fetch = require("node-fetch");

getHubspotData('https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/paged?hapikey=demo&properties=dealname&properties=dealstage&properties=closedate&properties=dealtype&properties=type&properties=hubspot_owner_id&properties=amount&properties=notes_last_updated&includeAssociations=true');

function getHubspotData(url) {
    console.log("URL: " + url);
    fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function () {
            var x = 2;
        }).then(function (x) {
            console.log(x);
        })

}
```

I get undefined when I try to console.log the value of x

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the value of `2` from that `.then()` handler so that it becomes the resolved value of the promise for the next `.then()` handler.

```
function getHubspotData(url) {
    console.log("URL: " + url);
    return fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return 2;                // set resolved value of promise
        }).then(function (x) {
            console.log(x);          // outputs 2
        });

}
```